# If a user has posted wrong code in question, then should edits in questions correct the user's code as well?

Tags: discussion

Recently, a user asked a question on `c` language. He had some errors in his code though. I thought the problem is in his code so I answered his question with the rectified version of his code. Then someone edited the question and edited the code in the question to reflect the correct code. Since now my answer code and the question code match, people who watched this post later voted my answer down since now it is the exact copy of the question code and does not show any change or correction.
Is this legit? Should I remove my answer?

My concern is that if the OP intentionally posted the wrong code, will he not be confused on seeing the edited question? The one who edited will just tell what he edited and will not explain why he edited. How is such a situation handled?

Comment: Do you have a link to the post? Was the question about what was wrong with the code? Did you add explanation on what you had done, so people just seeing a block of code wouldn't have thought you just copied and pasted the OP's code, without changes?

Comment: No it's not right. If you add a link to the question we'll roll it back to the state it was in when you answered it.

Comment: here's the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37275549/when-i-use-two-consecutive-gets-statements-the-first-one-is-skipped/37276267?noredirect=1#comment62084103_37276267

Comment: @Draken Yeah I explained my answer by saying the OP what I had modified and why but now it might seem a little odd to view that answer.

Comment: Looks like the question has been rolled back now.

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes, Thanks for the attention and help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edits to OP's code are sketchy in general.  That's what the OP is currently using, so changing the code in the question is not helpful.  After all, they might get a "solution" to a problem that isn't actually the one they asked about.  If the OP had given some indication that the mistakes you pointed out were not important (via approving the edit or commenting), that's a bit different.  But there is no indication that the edits to the code represent the OP's problem.  In this case, a rollback is appropriate ([thanks @Makoto](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37275549/8)).

However, questions often have deeper problems than just some minor code typos.  So if your answer is brittle enough to depend on those specifics, there could be room to expand your answer.  Fixing these kinds of errors is often a good first step, but these fixes don't always fix the entire problem.

Comment: I agree with you. But in my case, the user had a simple issue (if you saw the question) which I thought was due to his wrong code so changing the question wasn't of much help.